# Rails models for Users, Offers, Comments, Documents, and Reviews

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, database, active-record

I want to simplify my Rails models, current looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :offers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :documents, as: :documentable
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :offer
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :offer
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :documentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

As you can see, I have the same relations on Comment and Review models, but they have some difference in columns, what are the options do I have to minimize the amount of models?

[image]

Comment: Why the desire for fewer models? If a review is different from a comment, then let them be different models. Maybe share some code via modules/concerns, but I see no reason to conflate the two just for the sake of "fewer models"

Comment: @Flambino because I noticed duplication in Review and Comment models, and I was thinking that there's more elegant way of doing this

Comment: I'd say the most elegant way is to model your domain as best you can. If that means more models, then more models it is. Functionality-wise those models can share code (e.g. modules/concerns); less _code_ is a good thing, but fewer models isn't a goal in and of itself. As long as a comment is somehow not the same as a review, and vice-versa, don't try to make it one-size-fits-all. It's more likely to end up as one-size-fits-none. And should the two diverge more in functionality later, you'll want distinct models anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is if they are different treat them different. You can share code with help of interaction or service of some other way may be with active `active_interaction`. But if you really want to have less table then you may define one single model say `Content` and this will have a column `content_type: integer` with default value as 0 and all your other columns then convert the content_type to enum something like below

```
class Content < ApplicationRecord
  enum content_type: { comment: 0, rating: 1 }
end
```

this will help you to differentiate between comment and rating. With proper indexing it will make no issue.